# Thread safe Shareable and Splittable Buffer with Safe Memory (Project)

Tags: multithreading, linked-list, error-handling, memory-management, ada

### Backstory

This is a buffer I wrote for use in multiple personal projects. It is designed
to handle pretty much any data in pretty much any way. In particular I intend to
use it in such instances as recursive-descent parsers, where it will be
important to be able to 'undo' operations.

### Undo

This 'undo' functionality is implemented alongside thread safety by maintaining
references to a 'reference' object. Thus a buffer can be copied in a (mostly)
shallow manner while maintaining the same underlying data. Removing from a copy
of a buffer doesn't actually remove its 'head' node unless it is the last copy
of a buffer to reference it.

### Memory safety

The memory safety is achieved by re-using old nodes instead of freeing them if
possible and not allowing data to be inserted unless there is an already
allocated node available. This effectively implements a custom memory store.

### Memory and Thread Safety

I had quite a bit of headache trying to get this to be both threadsafe and
devoid of memory leaks. I believe I have finally achieved that. There were a lot
of off-by-one errors that had to be corrected with respect to references and
null pointers to ensure that everything gets cleaned up when appropriate *and*
nothing gets cleaned up prematurely.

### Your Task

The reason I am posting this here is because I intend to re-use this
implementation a lot. As such I want to make sure it doesn't have any bugs
later. While I don't expect subtle memory or thread-safety bugs to be easily
detected, any stylistic changes that may be allowing such bugs to hide would be
nice to detect early.

Therefore if there are any areas where a slight change of methodology could get
more inherent safety, I would greatly appreciate it. I was surprised by how
finicky this was, considering that Ada typically makes it harder to actually
make surface-level mistakes.

If I had to point to one thing I'm not happy about it would be that each node is its own protected object. I would have thought it would be doable with only the reference list being protected and using its mutual exclusion to reference count the nodes. I just couldn't find a way to make that work.

### Specification

```
with Ada.Finalization;

generic
    type Element is private;

    -- 0 capacity means use entire accessible memory pool
    Max_Capacity : Natural := 0;

    -- Total number of nodes to cache for re-use
    Max_Cache : Positive := 1;
package Shared_Buffers is
    type Shared_Buffer is new Ada.Finalization.Controlled with private;

    procedure Insert (Into : in out Shared_Buffer; Value : Element);
    procedure Remove (From : in out Shared_Buffer; Value : out Element);

    function Has_Data (What : Shared_Buffer) return Boolean;

    procedure Initialize (Object : in out Shared_Buffer);
    procedure Adjust (Object : in out Shared_Buffer);
    procedure Finalize (Object : in out Shared_Buffer);
private
    type Element_Node;
    type Element_Node_Access is access Element_Node;
    type Node_List is array (Positive range <>) of Element_Node_Access;

    protected type Element_Node is
        -- Reference counting features
        procedure Reference (Times : Positive := 1);
        procedure Ignore;
        procedure Clear;
        function Has_References return Boolean;
        function Get_References return Natural;

        -- Node features
        procedure Set (Value : Element);
        procedure Follow_With (Node : Element_Node_Access);
        function Get return Element;
        function Next return Element_Node_Access;
        entry Wait;
    private
        Data : Element;
        Following : Element_Node_Access := null;
        References : Natural := 1;
    end Element_Node;

    protected type Protected_Shared_Buffer is
        -- Reference counting features
        procedure Reference (From : Element_Node_Access);
        procedure Ignore;
        function Has_References return Boolean;

        -- Buffer features
        entry Insert (Value : Element);
        entry Get_Head (Node : out Element_Node_Access);
        procedure Remove (Node : in out Element_Node_Access);
        function Has_Head return Boolean;
    private
        Tail : Element_Node_Access := null;
        Head : Element_Node_Access := null;

        Cache : Node_List (1 .. Max_Cache) :=
            (1 => new Element_Node, others => null);
        Cached : Natural := 1;
        Count : Natural := 1;

        References : Natural := 1;
        Newborns : Natural := 1;
    end Protected_Shared_Buffer;

    type Protected_Shared_Buffer_Access is access Protected_Shared_Buffer;

    type Shared_Buffer is new Ada.Finalization.Controlled with
        record
            Reference : Protected_Shared_Buffer_Access;
            Self : Element_Node_Access;
            Tailed : Boolean;
        end record;
end Shared_Buffers;
```

### Body

```
with Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation;

package body Shared_Buffers is
    procedure Free_Node is new Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation
        (Element_Node, Element_Node_Access);

    procedure Free_Protected_Shared_Buffer is new Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation
        (Protected_Shared_Buffer, Protected_Shared_Buffer_Access);

    protected body Element_Node is
        procedure Reference (Times : Positive := 1) is begin
            References := References + Times;
        end Reference;

        procedure Ignore is begin
            if References > 0 then
                References := References - 1;
            end if;
        end Ignore;

        procedure Clear is begin
            References := 0;
        end Clear;

        function Has_References return Boolean is (References > 0);
        function Get_References return Natural is (References);

        procedure Set (Value : Element) is begin
            Data := Value;
        end Set;

        procedure Follow_With (Node : Element_Node_Access) is begin
            Following := Node;
        end Follow_With;

        function Get return Element is (Data);

        function Next return Element_Node_Access is (Following);

        entry Wait when Following /= null is begin null; end Wait;
    end Element_Node;

    protected body Protected_Shared_Buffer is
        procedure Reference (From : Element_Node_Access) is
            Node : Element_Node_Access := From;
        begin
            References := References + 1;

            if From = null then
                Newborns := Newborns + 1;
            end if;

            while Node /= null loop
                Node.Reference;
                Node := Node.Next;
            end loop;
        end Reference;

        procedure Ignore is begin
            if References > 1 then
                References := References - 1;
            else
                References := 0;
                for I in Positive range 1 .. Cached loop
                    Free_Node (Cache (I));
                    Count := Count - 1;
                end loop;
            end if;
        end Ignore;

        function Has_References return Boolean is (References > 0);

        entry Insert (Value : Element) when Cached > 0 is
            Node : Element_Node_Access := Cache (Cached);
        begin
            Node.Clear;
            Node.Set (Value);

            if Tail = null then
                Node.Reference (Newborns);
                Head := Node;
            else
                Node.Reference (Tail.Get_References);
                Tail.Follow_With (Node);
            end if;

            Tail := Node;

            if Max_Capacity = 0 or Count < Max_Capacity then
                Cache (Cached) := new Element_Node;
                Count := Count + 1;
            else
                Cached := Cached - 1;
            end if;
        exception
            when Storage_Error =>
                Cached := Cached - 1;
        end Insert;

        entry Get_Head (Node : out Element_Node_Access) when Head /= null is
        begin
            Node := Head;
            Newborns := Newborns - 1;
        end Get_Head;

        procedure Remove (Node : in out Element_Node_Access) is begin
            Node.Ignore;

            if not Node.Has_References then
                if Cached = Max_Cache then
                    Free_Node (Node);
                    Count := Count - 1;
                else
                    Cached := Cached + 1;
                    Cache (Cached) := Node;
                end if;
            end if;
        end Remove;

        function Has_Head return Boolean is (Head /= null);
    end Protected_Shared_Buffer;

    procedure Insert (Into : in out Shared_Buffer; Value : Element) is
    begin
        Into.Reference.Insert (Value);
    end Insert;

    procedure Remove (From : in out Shared_Buffer; Value : out Element) is
        Next : Element_Node_Access;
    begin
        if From.Tailed then
            if From.Self /= null then
                From.Self.Wait;
                Next := From.Self.Next;

                From.Reference.Remove (From.Self);
                From.Self := Next;
            else
                From.Reference.Get_Head (From.Self);
            end if;
        end if;

        Value := From.Self.Get;
        Next := From.Self.Next;

        if Next /= null then
            From.Reference.Remove (From.Self);
            From.Self := Next;
            From.Tailed := False;
        else
            From.Tailed := True;
        end if;
    end Remove;

    function Has_Data (What : Shared_Buffer) return Boolean is
        (if What.Tailed then (
            if What.Self /= null then
                What.Self.Next /= null
            else
                What.Reference.Has_Head));

    procedure Initialize (Object : in out Shared_Buffer) is
    begin
        Object.Reference := new Protected_Shared_Buffer;

        Object.Self := null;
        Object.Tailed := True;
    end Initialize;

    procedure Adjust (Object : in out Shared_Buffer) is
    begin
        Object.Reference.Reference (Object.Self);
    end Adjust;

    procedure Finalize (Object : in out Shared_Buffer) is
        Removed : Element_Node_Access;
    begin
        if not Object.Tailed then
            while Object.Self /= null loop
                Removed := Object.Self;
                Object.Self := Object.Self.Next;
                Object.Reference.Remove (Removed);
            end loop;
        end if;

        Object.Reference.Ignore;
        if not Object.Reference.Has_References then
            Free_Protected_Shared_Buffer (Object.Reference);
        end if;
    end Finalize;
end Shared_Buffers;
```